# I want to secure azure function using Authorization level

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management

I have an azure function. And I want to make it secure using Authorization Level.function i.e using x-function-key. I have an azure sdk for local development. What should happen when securing azure function?
How it will provide security and against what? I am using ASP.NET.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Functions lets you use keys to make it harder to access your HTTP function endpoints during development.

To secure an endpoint in production you need to use authentication + Authorization using the options:

1. App service Authentication.
2. Azure API Management.
3. Deploy the function app to Azure App Service Environment.

details in this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook?tabs=csharp#secure-an-http-endpoint-in-production

Comment: Is there any way to secure it locally...like i didnt publish my function app. Can it be secured in any way???